# Tryinf to run existing scripts in shell gives "command not found"

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

I am trying to install Anaconda with a sh script.
I am using Ubuntu 18.

Here is my Downloads folder. We can clearly see the script

```
sgerodes@sgerodes-TECRA-A50-EC  ~/Downloads  ls -al
total 564196
drwxr-xr-x  2 sgerodes sgerodes      4096 Aug  7 09:43  .
drwxr-xr-x 45 sgerodes sgerodes      4096 Aug  7 09:43  ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 sgerodes sgerodes 576830621 Aug  7 09:36  Anaconda3-2020.07-Linux-x86_64.sh
-rw-rw-r--  1 sgerodes sgerodes    868673 Aug  4 16:32 'Dokumentation Zeitplanung & Auslastung_Teams.pptx'
-rw-rw-r--  1 sgerodes sgerodes     16042 Mai 25 18:50  hw1-11.gif
-rw-rw-r--  1 sgerodes sgerodes      3185 Jun 25 18:19  j-koop-meyer.impex
```

But running it gives a "command not found".

```
sgerodes@sgerodes-TECRA-A50-EC  ~/Downloads  sudo ./Anaconda3-2020.07-Linux-x86_64.sh 
sudo: ./Anaconda3-2020.07-Linux-x86_64.sh: command not found

sgerodes@sgerodes-TECRA-A50-EC  ~/Downloads  sudo Anaconda3-2020.07-Linux-x86_64.sh 
sudo: Anaconda3-2020.07-Linux-x86_64.sh: command not found
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see from the permissions `-rw-rw-r--`  that it is not executable. If you do:

```
chmod a+x Anaconda3-2020.07-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

then you should see the permissions become `-rwxrwxr-x`. You can now do:

```
sudo ./Anaconda3-2020.07-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

and it should work.